# Proving that $P\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}, x_{5}\right)=\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, 0,0,0\right)$ is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, solution-verification

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{C}^5$ and the map
$$P\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}, x_{5}\right)=\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, 0,0,0\right)$$
I want to prove that it is linear. I argue that from the property of vector addition that it can be proven by:
$$P(\alpha x+\beta y)=P\left(\alpha\left[\begin{array}{l}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{array}\right]+\beta\left[\begin{array}{l}
y_{1} \\
y_{2} \\
y_{3} \\
y_{4} \\
y_{5}
\end{array}\right]\right)=P\left(\left[\begin{array}{l}
\alpha x_{1}+\beta y_{1} \\
\alpha x_{2}+\beta y_{2} \\
\alpha x_{3}+\beta y_{3} \\
\alpha x_{4}+\beta y_{4} \\
\alpha x_{5}+\beta y_{5}
\end{array}\right]\right)\\
=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\alpha x_{1}+\beta y_{1} \\
\alpha x_{2}+\beta y_{2} \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right]=\alpha\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right]+\beta\left[\begin{array}{c}
y_{2} \\
y_{2} \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right]=\alpha P(x)+\beta P(y)$$
Did I 'break any laws', or is this the correct way to show that it is linear?

Comment: No, you are a law abiding citizen -:)

Comment: Great, thank you. :)